# MYSQL query not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql query---

```
               $query="SELECT * FROM `wall_posts`
                       WHERE 
                       `login_name` = '" . $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN'] . "'
                       OR
                       `login_name` IN (
                       SELECT friend_login
                       FROM friends
                       )
                       ORDER BY time DESC";
```

But when I execute it, it does'nt give me expected results also only one post is being displayed!

Comment: What **is** the expected result?

Comment: That all the post related to the login names in the friends table.

Comment: The cause of one post being returned is so broad. There may actually only be one post, could be the way you are reading the result, etc...

Comment: interpolating values (such as `$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN']`) into queries is dangerous. It may be safe in this instance, but in others you could be opening your site to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To prevent this, always use parameters in [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements) for values. Note that only simple values can be parameterized. Table names, column names, compound values and the like still need to be (carefully) interpolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running it directly from within a mysql console/phpmyadmin?
And what is in `friends`? Is it a relation table? In that case you should probably add a `WHERE` somewhere because now you are selecting everything.

This code should return more then just 1 row if there are more. Perhaps your problem is in the way you display the results. What is the result of:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo 'Number of rows: ' . mysql_num_rows($result);
```